# POST an image using django-restless

Tags: django, rest

I am using [django-restless](https://github.com/toastdriven/restless/) and I want to pass an image in a POST request.

I searched in the documentation looking for something related to passing a file/image in a request, but I couldnt find.

Can someone help me on how to use django-restless with images?

FYI, my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    prefix = models.CharField('prefix', max_length=10, unique=True, editable=False, null=True)
    input_image = models.ImageField('Input image')
```

my resource:

```
class MyModelResource(DjangoResource):
    preparer = FieldsPreparer(fields={
        'input_image': 'input_image_url',
        'id': 'id',
    })

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @skip_prepare
    def list(self):
        return list(MyModel.objects.all().values('id'))

    def update(self):
        raise MethodNotAllowed()

    def delete(self):
        raise MethodNotAllowed()

    def detail(self, pk):
        return MyModel.objects.get(id=pk)

    def create(self):
        input_image = SimpleUploadedFile('', base64.b64decode(self.data['input_image']), "application/octet-stream")

        return CountProcess.objects.create(input_image=input_image)
```

and its not working right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that django-restless supports multipart form data. I solved creating an usual `ModelForm` and added it to my `Resource` like this:

```
class MyModelResource(DjangoResource):
    preparer = FieldsPreparer(fields={
        'input_image': 'input_image_url',
        'id': 'id',
    })

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @skip_prepare
    def list(self):
        return list(MyModel.objects.all().values('id'))

    def update(self):
        raise MethodNotAllowed()

    def delete(self):
        raise MethodNotAllowed()

    def detail(self, pk):
        return MyModel.objects.get(id=pk)

    def create(self):
        form = MyModelForm(self.request, self.data, self.request.FILES)
        obj = None

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()

        return obj
```